# anchor mailto multiple lines

Tags: html, css, anchor, mailto

I can't seem to find out if this is possible or not. I am wanting to have an anchor mailto tag on multiple lines.

I am unable to insert a break in the url because when I copy it, it will add the break into the address.

Heres something I have so far. I havent figured out the best css to make this work properly.

```
<a class="email" href="mailto:hello@email.com"><span class="hello">hello@</span><span class="domain">email.com</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:block` to the span tags:

```
.hello, .domain {
   display:block;   
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gGTEN/

It will copy/paste without the "line breaks".